# When do GeoJSON feature collections need feature ids?

Tags: geojson

I've seen feature collections with feature ids for each feature.  I've seen others with no featureid.

When do you need it?

Answer (score 5):

Typically any system that has/transmits some unique information identifying a record sends it so that modifications to that record (in this case, a feature) are recognized in later analysis.

That is, if a piece of software sends out subsets of itself as GeoJSON, or accepts GeoJSON as input to modify an existing data store (say a table in PostGIS), then a unique identifier is needed. However, in general, GeoJSON does not require any unique identifier for simple data interchange and [no such concept is expressed in the standard](http://geojson.org/geojson-spec.html#feature-objects).

In short: in GeoJSON, there is not any defined situation where it is required. Downstream applications may require it to match up GeoJSON records to records in a database.